# access variable containing query in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am using Sessions to pass query from one controller to another. I am stuck accessing the variable containing the same query on another controller.
The sessions used on First controller is:

```
$this->session->set_userdata('item', $this->view_data['search_results']);
```

Second Controller:

```
$search_results = $this->session->userdata('item');
var_dump($search_results);
```

I am getting the results in $search_results. The problem I am facing is I want to append some other filter condition to same query ! How should I access Query contained in $search_results.

Comment: actually what you want to do ?, hav you impliment a search or anything else ?

Comment: I am getting a result query from a search engine i used. I want to append some further filtration to same query.

Comment: you are setting result in session. Not query. Then where is the query stored? Mention clearly. Then only we can give suggestion to append the filter to query.

Comment: if you want to append more query then you make $search_result as an array like this $search_result = array ( 'item' => $this->session->userdata('item') );

Answer (score 0):

Why not to send the query itself, along with the **search_result** data!

```
view_data['search_query'] = // you are going to need to have your query for get it sent
view_data['search_results'] = // array result of your query ran in the model function

$this->session->set_userdata('item', $this->view_data[]);
```

You can access $search_query in the second controller!

Comment: How can I append another query to $search_query ?

Comment: let us see your queries!